# I am getting an error when I running node command

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

I am getting an error when I hit

```
npm -v or node
```

Actually, this happens after I tried a command to update my npm version from 3.5.2 to version 4 or higher. The command I used is this:

```
sudo ln -sf ~/.nvm/versions/node/v8.5.0/bin/node /usr/bin/nodejs
```

Now as soon as I hit the

```
node
```

it is throwing an error saying

> bash: /usr/bin/npm: No such file or directory

After this I uninstalled node and reinstalled but it's not working. Please help me.

Update: Node is now not getting removed. Permission denied is coming up as the error.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/250971/no-such-file-or-directory-error-while-using-npm

Comment: fire `~/.nvm/versions/node/v8.5.0/bin/node` and tell me what happens

Comment: Also, are you using `nvm`? Did you install nodejs using nvm the first time?

Comment: @DushyantBangal, No I have not installed node using nvm, and when I ran your query it returned as - bash: /home/umar/.nvm/versions/node/v8.5.0/bin/node: No such file or directory

Comment: I am new to ubuntu, I was trying to update my npm version, but during the process I came across a command which I mastakenly for the update of npm version, which I shouldn't, and it is causing now problem. EVen I cannot uninstall node js.

Comment: See, basically the command you fired was for creating a shortcut, and not upgrading. It only works when your new version is at `~/.nvm/versions/node/v8.5.0/bin/node`

Comment: try `sudo apt purge node*`.
This will try and remove all `node*` packages